# ubuntu 14.04: blinking font and mouse pointer

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I encountered the following problem: after a usual boot I got a blinking mouse pointer and font (i.e. changing in size up and down). Got a message "Ubuntu 14.04 internal error" as well, but couldn't do a printscreen with the details. Another thing is that when I try to shut down and choose "shut down" in the upper-right corner menu, I never get a usual "restart/shut down" window, but "lock/log off" instead.

Any ideas, what it can be?

ps. I've already checked display settings and there is only one built-in display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, enter a console as it seems you can't really do much with your current setup.

To do this type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

You should now have a login prompt that looks somewhat like this:

```
Ubuntu (some version number) (computer name) TTY1

(computer name) login:
```

Now type your username, press enter, type your password, and press enter again. If all goes well, you should have a logged in terminal session.

I don't fully know what's wrong with your installation but I guess it has something to do with your configuration files. (If you could get some more information out of the error dialog ie what package crashed that would help a lot)

**Corrupted Configuration Files:**

To remedy (in terminal) type these commands

```
mkdir oldconfigs #create a directory to hold all the possibly corrupted configuration files
mv .* oldconfigs #move all configuration files to the oldconfigs directory.
sudo reboot now # reboot the computer
```

If you need to restore some of these configuration files later, they will still be safe in the oldconfigs directory.

Comment: Thank you! Some awkward things were still left, but after updating all the packages and upgrading to 14.04.1 everything is ok.

Comment: Good :). Could you mark my answer as correct if it helped :D.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My problem was solved by using this command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```